# Why is onWillPop in WillPopScope ignored when using Navigator.pop?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a [`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to try to stop a route from popping:

```dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    print('This is never called');
    return false;
  }
)
```

When I use [`Navigator.pop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html), the current route is simply popped instead of `onWillPop` being called:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is **by design**.

You will have to use [`Navigator.maybePop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/maybePop.html):

> Tries to pop the current route of the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context, while honoring the route's [Route.willPop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/willPop.html) state.

This means that only *`Navigator.maybePop`* honors [`onWillPop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html) and `Navigator.pop` **does not**:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
```

Comment: Thankyou, there was a serious bug in my app, and by your answer bug is solved. Thank you so much.